# Finding a node if a brother is unique

Tags: xml, xpath, dtd

I have a DTD line like this :

```
<!ELEMENT performance (composition, (soloist)?,(orchestra, conductor)?)>
```

And i would like to find the compositions where there is only one soloist.

I thought about something like this :

```
/performance/compositions[count(../soloist)=1]
```

Is it correct ? 
Is it possible to have AND operator in predicate ? (if i want no soloist and one orchestra, for exemple)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the declaration for `performance` only allows zero or one `soloist` and zero or one `orchestra`, there is no need to count the number of occurrences.

To return `composition`'s that have a `soloist`:

```
    /performance[soloist]/composition
```

To return `composition`'s that do not have a `soloist` and have an `orchestra`:

```
    /performance[not(soloist) and orchestra]/composition
```

Comment: Oh, i didn't think about that. Is it possible to test values of soloist (for exemple) to choose a composition ? Something like    /performance[soloist='John Doe']/composition ?

Comment: @Csi - Yes that's possible and your xpath looks correct. See here for more info on predicates: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates